# Using dedicated record storage page in TYPO3 extension

Tags: plugins, typo3

I wrote a TYPO3 extension with Kickstarter and want to know if it is possible to add a storagepage for the "plugin".

At the moment I use the general storage page for the whole page, but this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Using [flexform](http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_using_Flexforms),you can provide "general storage page " as your plug-in option and it keep one storage folder for a plugin

You need to include:

```
 // get data from Flexform:
    $this->pi_initPIflexForm();
// Vars
    $this->showMorelink = $this->pi_getFFvalue($this->cObj->data['pi_flexform'], 'show_morelink', 's_template');
```

locallang_tca.xml   :

```
                <label index="tt_plugin.pi_flexform.show_morelink">records</label>
```

flexform_ds.xml :

```
          <show_morelink>
           <TCEforms>
            <label>LLL:EXT:tt_plugin/locallang_tca.xml:tt_plugin.show_morelink</label>
            <config>
             <type>check</type>
            </config>
           </TCEforms>
          </show_morelink>
```